# Interesting question with ordering integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, ordered-fields

The numbers $1,2,3,...,101$ are written down in a row in some order. Is it always possible to cross out $90$ numbers in a way such that all $11$ numbers left will stay either in increasing or in decreasing order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, and this is due to a result of Erdos and Szekeres.
A particular case of their theorem states that : for every sequence of $n^2+1$ real numbers, there is either an increasing or decreasing subsequence of length $n+1$.

The proof is either by Pigeonhole Principle or Dilworth's Theorem and can be found here: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős–Szekeres_theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem)